# How can I move \captionof inside a minipage?

Tags: captions, minipage

I'm trying to put a figure next to a table using minipages. Both elements are going to have their caption, but I can't manage to align the captions to the centre of each one.

This is the code so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish,activeacute]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{0.3\linewidth}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{$T (K)$} & \textbf{$n_i (cm^{-3})$} \\ \hline \hline
77               & $1.538 \cdot 10^{-4}$    \\ \hline
100              & $25.294$         \\ \hline
130              & $2.966 \cdot 10^{5}$     \\ \hline
160              & $1.1061\cdot 10^{8}$     \\ \hline
190              & $6.6488 \cdot 10^{10}$   \\ \hline
220              & $1.3509 \cdot 10^{11} $  \\ \hline
250              & $1.3655 \cdot 10^{12} $  \\ \hline
280              & $8.5717\cdot 10^{12}$    \\ \hline
310              & $3.8301 \cdot 10^{13}$   \\ \hline
340              & $1.3310\cdot 10^{14}$    \\ \hline
370              & $3.8204\cdot 10^{14}$    \\ \hline
400              & $9.4473\cdot 10^{14}$    \\ \hline
430              & $2.0752\cdot 10^{15}$    \\ \hline
460              & $4.1418\cdot 10^{15}$    \\ \hline
490              & $7.6415\cdot 10^{15}$    \\ \hline
500              & $9.2318\cdot 10^{15}$    \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\captionof{table}{}

\end{minipage}\hspace{-2 em}
\begin{minipage}{0.65\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{ni_T.png}
    \vspace{-2 em}\captionof{figure}{$n_i$ en función de la temperatura en escala logarítmica.}
    
\end{minipage}%
\vspace{2cm}

\end{document}
```

Which yields

[image]

And you can see, the captions are not quite centered with neither the table or the figure.
I've tried using `\hspace` before `\captionof` and also tried with `\centering` before the figure and after it (above `\captionof`). But the caption doesn't even move. I've only achieved to move it vertically.

Any way to do this? Or any better manner to approach this?

Comment: Please note that others cannot copy and test your code (please make it complete but minimal). You might also want to have a look at the `siunitx` package to properly format units, it can even help in formatting the table.

Comment: I would do it with the `floatrow` package.

Comment: you could try `\begin{minipage}[b]...`

Comment: To horizontally center table and caption inside the first minipage, add `\centering` before `\begin{tabular}`. To improve the alignment in the second minipage, remove `\vspace` and `\hspace` and add `\hfill`between the first `\end{minipage}` and the second `\begin{minipage}`.

Comment: Entirely unrelated to the alignment issue itself, but you may want to use the `siunitx` package for improved representation of units and probably also for improved alignment and easier inupt of numbers in your table. To furter inprove the readability of your table, you might also want to consider removing all vertical and most of the horizont lines.

Comment: The caption IS centered relative to the minipage, which overlaps the table to the left by 2em plus any excess width inside the left minipage.  You also need a \noindent before the first minipage, and shrink the contents to fit the space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This measures the width of the table and shrinks the image to use the remaining width (minus `\columnsep`).

I also aligned the bottoms of the table and image (not the captions).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish,activeacute]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{showframe}% alignment tool, MWE only

\newsavebox{\tempbox}

\begin{document}

\savebox{\tempbox}{\begin{tabular}[b]{|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{$T (K)$} & \textbf{$n_i (cm^{-3})$} \\ \hline \hline
77               & $1.538 \cdot 10^{-4}$    \\ \hline
100              & $25.294$         \\ \hline
130              & $2.966 \cdot 10^{5}$     \\ \hline
160              & $1.1061\cdot 10^{8}$     \\ \hline
190              & $6.6488 \cdot 10^{10}$   \\ \hline
220              & $1.3509 \cdot 10^{11} $  \\ \hline
250              & $1.3655 \cdot 10^{12} $  \\ \hline
280              & $8.5717\cdot 10^{12}$    \\ \hline
310              & $3.8301 \cdot 10^{13}$   \\ \hline
340              & $1.3310\cdot 10^{14}$    \\ \hline
370              & $3.8204\cdot 10^{14}$    \\ \hline
400              & $9.4473\cdot 10^{14}$    \\ \hline
430              & $2.0752\cdot 10^{15}$    \\ \hline
460              & $4.1418\cdot 10^{15}$    \\ \hline
490              & $7.6415\cdot 10^{15}$    \\ \hline
500              & $9.2318\cdot 10^{15}$    \\ \hline
\end{tabular}}% measure width

\noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{\wd\tempbox}
  \usebox\tempbox
  \captionof{table}{}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr \linewidth-\wd\tempbox-\columnsep}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
    \vspace{-2 em}\captionof{figure}{$n_i$ en función de la temperatura en escala logarítmica.}
\end{minipage}%
\vspace{2cm}

\end{document}
```

[image: deom]